# Javascript stockchart graph

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am pretty new to Javascript and I am trying to execute this stockchart to work fine from this URL: http://jsfiddle.net/2zBRt/2/

```
     The code is excatly the same from the URL, some minor changes are made to ensure that the JQuery library is called
```

However I keep getting this error :

> (1) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDefaults' of undefined
>
> (2) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'datepicker'

```
Code:
    function(chart){

          // apply the date pickers
          setTimeout(function(){
              $('input.highcharts-range-selector',   

$('#'+chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
          },0)   

     });


    // Set the datepicker's date format
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
          this.onchange();
          this.onblur();
      }
  });
```

Please help me out, my Boss is breathing heavily down my neck

Answer (score 0):

As i know , these two functions didn't define yet, so it said the function undefine

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('input.highcharts-range-selector',   
   $('#'+chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
},0)
```

this function use datepicker() function, but it doesn't define before

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
          this.onchange();
          this.onblur();
      }
```

same problem, doesn't define yet

Comment: How do i define the functions?

Comment: it seems, datepicker is a CLASS and setDefaults is the method of datepicker, or simply delete these two function, the chart still working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have compatible versions of jQuery and jQuery `UI`, for example when included properly in jsfiddle, it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2zBRt/41/